# Arduino controlled robot : without uploading every time

Tags: arduino

I've recently built an Arduino-controlled robot(4WD platform) using a beginner's kit.

After uploading compiled program into Arduino, I was able to get 4WD motors working.

But when I disconnect the USB cable after successful "uploading" and I turn on the mobile platform switch, it doesn't move a bit.

What procedure is required for getting it to move (I mean.. having machine language permanently stored in AVR microcontroller's memory) without again connecting USB cable to Arduino and uploading program after I find the code working so that just turning on the switch of the robot make it start to move as programmed?

[image]

Comment: The Arduino stores the program in Flash memory, it's not like an FPGA. It is permanently there. Make sure you have strong enough battery in the robot, I guess.. or check for some other fault.

Comment: Hi, MightyPork. I believe so. I remember it working even after I disconnected USB cable and just turned on the switch. Maybe it didn't move due to power problem or motor shied(Adafruit)'s disconnection from Arduino. Thank you for your tip.

Comment: Code is at https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Motor_Shield_V2_Library

Answer (score 2):

It **REALLY** sounds like a power issue.

-What is powering your arduino when the USB is disconnected?

The USB from a computer is often pretty strong (hight current) and a 9V battery might not cut it for electric motors and such.

If this is the problem you may want to try a more powerfull battery setup, like 4 AAs.

You may go the LiPo battery route from a source like Adafruit or Sparkfun. Then the problem is that a LiPo battery only produces 3.3V. Ugh, you'll need an circuit to bump the voltage to 5 (which Adafruit sells) and a charger. This may be your best choice if you're planning to use the robot a lot.

Comment: It REALLY was a power issue. My workaround was to connect another power source to Arduino itself.~~